# No gap in plywood sheathing

Tags: plywood, gap

Shortly after a new roof was installed in my home, following wet weather, I noticed two bulges in my new roof.  I called the roofer and he promptly came out and fixed it by taking out the shingles over the bulges then cutting the plywood and renailing it down.  It was after he did this that I realized there was a problem with the installation of the plywood.  He told me there was no problem with the installation, and was not sure why the buckling occurred.  After he left, I inspected the plywood from the attic and found that they had failed to lay down the sheets with a 1/8" gap between pieces.

What can/should I do at this point?  It appears the entire job was done without the required gap and I fear the buckling will continue.

Comment: It seems like perhaps the issue is that your roof deck got wet and expanded.

Comment: Yes, we had wet weather following the installation. My fear is this will continue to happen throughout the roof.  Trying to determine my options at this point.

Comment: Get your roofer and their warranty company on the horn?

Comment: Moisture content (MC) in the plywood is EVERYTHING here. If the plywood is tight and the plywood has high MC about 10-14% checked with a moisture meter. during the wet/humid season, and has not buckled, you may be good. Now if it is tight in the dry season, with low MC about 4-8%, there is a chance that more buckles will be possible. This is  a comment only because it really can't answer your question because there are a few things still needed to be known. But IMHO, this guy who fixed it does know, and that is how it is fixed, doing what he did.

Comment: Thanks.  That was helpful. I'm trying to decide what my next move should be.  Since the entire roof sheathing appears to have been put in with no gaps at all, seems to that the only true remedy would be to tear it down and redo the entire project.  Not too sure if that is an option with a $35k roof.  I might just get an inspection done and sue the roofer.